How to get container image details in Kubernetes admission webhook?
Kubernetes provides a feature of calling web-hook "when objects are persisted" and particularly when pod is created. Such web-hook may even modify the way pod is created.
I'm trying to modify the CMD of the container, so the applications in pods are started with certain helper functionality. It is comparatively easy to do by adding patch field to the response of the webhook, in form of JSONPatch, e.g.
[{"op":"add", "path":"/spec/containers/0/command",
    "value":["sh", "-c", "echo test ; nginx -g 'daemon off;'"]}]

In this manner pod will execute echo test first and only then launches nginx (suppose
that nginx ... is the original command of the given image.
And here is the problem - how can I receive the content of original CMD and ENTRYPOINT?
Admission request - i.e. data which are received by the web-hook - seemingly contains only
limited information about container - particularly its exact image tag. But not detailed
content, like dockerfile.
Supposedly I need to use some kind of client to reach out image registry from the inside
of web-hook and pull details (as I know exact tag). Is there any suitable example and recommendations on the client to use (in go language)?
Alternatively, perhaps I'm missing some flag or feature in configuration of web-hook which will make Kubernetes pass more details in the request? By now it looks like this
(the file like webhook-configuration.yaml):
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: admission-webhook
  labels:
    app: webhook
    service: admission-webhook
webhooks:
  - name: admission-webhook
    clientConfig:
      service:
        name: admission-webhook
        namespace: webhook
        path: "/admission-review"
      caBundle: <certificate in base64>
    rules:
      - operations: [ "CREATE" ]
        apiGroups: ["*"]
        apiVersions: ["v1"]
        resources: ["pods"]
    sideEffects: None
    admissionReviewVersions: ["v1", "v1beta1"]

Thanks in advance!


Unless the Kubernetes manifest itself contains a command: override, this is hard to figure out.  This is true even in plain Docker.  Also see for example How do I run a Docker pre-entrypoint command without knowing the original entrypoint?  What is the actual command you're trying to inject?  Can you do it in an init container, rather than the main container?

@DavidMaze thanks for the insight, this gives me better idea of what is happening. The command modification just is to prepend it with some binary, which on execution, fetches secrets from known places in vault and propagates them into env variables, immediately calling target application from itself (so that these env variables are not seen outside anyway). I'll think about init container though not sure the same effect could be achieved.
